# vba PasteSpecial on same row

Tags: excel, vba

With the help of below coding, I am able to copy and past the filtered data to another sheet but it is pasting the data on 2nd row instead of taking last row.Not sure as to what went wrong.

```
With Sheets("Sheet3")    
    .Autofiler = False  
    .ShowAllData  
    .Range("A1:H28443").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="*Assign*", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="*SPID*"  
    Intersect(.UsedRange, .UsedRange.Offset(1)).SpecialCells`enter code here`(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy  
End With  

Sheets("DataSheet").Cells(1, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues  



With Sheets("Sheet3")  
    .Autofiler = False  
    .ShowAllData  
    .Range("A1:H28443").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="*Timeliness*", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="*Accuracy*"  
    Intersect(.UsedRange, .UsedRange.Offset(1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy  
End With  

Sheets("DataSheet").Cells(1, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: `Sheets("DataSheet").Cells(ROWS.COUNT, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

Comment: What you are doing wrong is that you are saying `Cells(1,1)` this is A1 and then you offset by 1 so Cell A2 is where you Paste. As @Jeeped said use `Cells(Rows.Count, 1)` to achive last used cell in column A

Comment: Thanks Jeedep... Your code is working fine.